# Why is my code printing illogical patterns everytime I run my node.js application?

Tags: node.js, redis, socket.io, publish-subscribe

I am creating a pub-sub application using node.js, redis, socket.io.

For my server side this is the code I have for app.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var redis = require('redis');
var http = require('http').Server(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(http);
var fs = require('fs');

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var sub = redis.createClient();
var pub = redis.createClient();

io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on('subscribe', function(channel){
sub.subscribe(channel);
console.log("Successfully subscribed");
});
socket.on('publish', function(msg, channel){
pub.publish(channel, msg);
if(pub.publish(channel, msg)){
  socket.emit('message', msg);
}
else{
  socket.emit('message', "The channel doesn't exist!");
  }
 })
})

http.listen(port, function(){
console.log('listening on port ' + port);
});
```

for index.js on the front-end, I am using jquery to fetch the html elements and use socket.io to communicate with the server:

```
$(function(){
$("#sub-btn").click(function(){
var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost');
var channelName = $("#channel").val();
var content = $('#content');
socket.emit('subscribe', channelName);
})
$("#pub-btn").click(function(){
var socket = new io.connect('http://localhost');
var msg = $("#published_message").val();
var channelName = $("#channel").val();
var content = $('#content');
socket.emit('publish', msg, channelName);
socket.on('message', function(msg){
  content.append(msg);
  })
 })
})
```

When I run my node application this is what I get:

[image: How it looks before entering anything]

After I insert some input for the first time, say for example:

[image: it works correctly]

After I insert some other input:

[image: It starts printing multiple times.]

I can't tell why this bug is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are appending new message to previous messages. this is where the bug happens!

```
var content = $('#content');
socket.emit('publish', msg, channelName);
socket.on('message', function(msg){
  content.append(msg);
  });
```

here when new message arrives, it appends to previous messages and cause the problem.

Comment: This is a borderline low quality answer. I won't vote to delete, but it would be _really good_ if you added some more content to your post.

Comment: thanks for your mention. I thought it's clear enough but you are right.

Comment: @MohammadRahchamani this is not the issue. even if I try console.log(msg), it is still doing it multiple times

Comment: you put console.log before append or after it?

Comment: instead of content.append